# Change package.json before creating new angular app

Tags: angular, npm, jasmine, dependencies, karma-jasmine

I am using Angular for the first time and I'm following a tutorial which is using angular/cli 8.3.6.  I'm trying to create a new app to use in a ASP.NET Core project, but I am running into a dependency conflict whenever I attempt the setup.

I'm running the command `ng new dutch-app --skip-git --inline-template --inline-style --skip-tests`  and I'm getting an error from npm that asks me to resolve a dependency error between two packages, jasmine-core and karma-jasmine-html-reporter.

npm is installing jasmine-core@3.4.0 and then trying to install  karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4, but that package needs a later version of jasmine-core.

Here's a screenshot of my terminal:

[image: Screenshot of my npm error message]

When I check the versions I have installed for both of these packages, npm says jasmine-core is v3.6.0, and karma-jasmine-html reporter is v1.5.4

I'm new but I think I understand what is happening.  I think that cli is creating a packages.json when it makes my app, and then npm installs the packages according to whats in that new packages.json in the new dutch-app directory.  However, probably due to the fact that I'm trying to use an old version of angular/cli, the packages.json contains dependency conflicts.

Is there a way for me to edit the packages.json in my app before npm begins to install packages?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this. I ran the ng command with `--skip-install`, then edited the packages.json in the app folder to fix the dependency conflict. Then, I just ran npm install.